# NRF24L01+ questions

Tags: wireless

Hello I have bought 2 NRF24L01+ (for instance: https://www.addicore.com/products/nrf24l01-pa-lna-with-antenna-2-4ghz-wireless-transceiver) in order to make a link between 2 Arduino. I am searching since the morning to find more information. For instance here: https://www.instructables.com/NRF24L01-Tutorial-Arduino-Wireless-Communication/ but I am more confused now. So I am asking them here.

1. The NRF24L01+ needs 3.3 Volt power supply but its SPI pins operate at 5 Volts? (!!)
2. What's the purpose of this adapter? https://www.addicore.com/products/nrf24l01-breakout-adapter-with-on-board-3-3v-regulator
3. In order to connect NRF24L01+ with Arduino GIGA R1, do I need the adapter or not?

Comment: NRF24L01+ is a chip. If you bought some modules with NRF24L01+ chip then we don't know what modules they are and how they work, so these questions can't be answered, unless you define what you bought.

Comment: For instance: https://www.addicore.com/products/nrf24l01-pa-lna-with-antenna-2-4ghz-wireless-transceiver